# How do I get the base64 string of a media with CameraRoll?

Tags: react-native, base64, camera-roll

When I get my local's image on React-native by using CameraRoll, I don't have a base64 string and I need it to register in database.
Is there a way to get it or have I to use an external package ?
I find react-native-image-base64 ([here](https://github.com/Snapp-FidMe/react-native-image-base64) but if there is another solution, I would prefer.

Thanks in advance for your response !

Answer (score 0):

read this doc
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagestore

you can get the base64 by getBase64ForTag(uri, success, failure)

```
    import {ImageStore} from "react-native";
.
.
.
         ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(uri, (data) => {
            this.setState({
              data: data,
            })
          }, e => console.warn("getBase64ForTag: ", e))
```

something like this

Comment: did u test this metod?